# What should my API return to Wordpress/jQuery after a form submission success/failure

Tags: forms, divi

I am using customized action (my own api) for Divi form submission, like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$('.customSubmit .et_pb_contact_form').attr('action', 'https://my-endpoint.com/api');
</script>
```

It executes fine, and my api is returning status 200 and following response body (JSON, utf8):

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "Form data received successfully"
}
```

However, on my page I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"success":true,"message":"Form data received successfully"}
at I.error (jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2:11769)
at Y (jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2:17234)
```

...etc

My question is: what response should my endpoint return for Divi (jQuery) to understand that form was submitted successfuly?